# Streaming Video from Google Drive Fails After Access Token Expires

Tags: ios, video, google-drive-api

My app streams video from Google Drive. When it requests the URL, it retrieves an access token, but that expires after an hour causing the buffer to empty and the video to freeze.

I'm familiar with the hour limit on access tokens but unsure of how to use the refresh token to request a new access token while a video is still streaming since that would change the URL AVPlayer is using. Any tips?

Comment: please add relevant link to the docs where it states on the access token expiry.

Comment: Thanks Shubhank, covered in section 4 of Google's doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2